# How to take the previous value and next value of the current loop?

Tags: python, list, project

I'm doing a heat index calculation project that will take the temperature and humidity values from files Temperature365.txt and Humidity365.txt ,
But if it found a value 0, I want it to take the previous value and next value to find the average and use that instead of 0.
For example
34
21
0
42

Instead of 0, I want to use the (21+42)/2 . But I mistakenly made it to take (21+34)/2, how do I change this code?

```
c1 = -8.78469475556
c2 = 1.61139411
c3 = 2.33854883889
c4 = -0.14611605
c5 = -0.012308094
c6 = -0.0164248277778
c7 = 2.211732 * 10**-3
c8 = 7.2546 * 10**-4
c9 = -3.582 * 10**-6

def whatstatus(hi_val):
    if hi_val >= 54:
        return "Extreme Danger"
    elif 41 <= hi_val < 54:
        return "Danger"
    elif 32 <= hi_val < 41:
        return "Extreme Caution"
    elif 27 <= hi_val < 32:
        return "Caution"
    else:
        return "Normal"

def cal_hi(T, H):
    Hi = c1 + (c2 * T) + (c3 * H) + (c4 * T * H) + (c5 * (T**2)) + (c6 * (H**2)) + (c7 * (T**2) * H) + (c8 * T * (H**2)) + (c9 * (T**2) * (H**2))
    return Hi

def handle_missing_values(data_list):
    """Fills missing values in a list using the average of the previous and next values (if available)."""
    if len(data_list) <= 1:
        return data_list  # Handle edge cases with 0 or 1 elements

    output_list = []
    for i in range(len(data_list)):
        if data_list[i] != 0:
            output_list.append(data_list[i])
        else:
            prev_value = data_list[max(i - 1, 0)]  # Safeguard against negative index
            next_value = data_list[min(i + 1, len(data_list) - 1)]  # Safeguard against exceeding list bounds
            if prev_value != 0 and next_value != 0:  # Check if both neighbors are valid
                output_list.append((prev_value + next_value) / 2)
            else:
                # Handle cases where only one neighbor is valid (or none)
                output_list.append(data_list[i])  # Maintain original value (0)

    return output_list

with open('Humidity365.txt') as Hf, open('Temperature365.txt') as Tf:
    print("Day\tTemperature(C)\tHumidity(%)\tHeat Index\tStatus", "\n", "---" * 22)

    Tlist = []
    Hlist = []

    for i, (Tl, Hl) in enumerate(zip(Tf, Hf)):
        Tx = float(Tl.strip())
        Hx = float(Hl.strip())

        # Specific fix for line 12 (index 11) using list comprehension
        if Hx == 0:  # Check for 0 value specifically at index 11
            prev_Hx = Hlist[i - 1]
            next_Hx = Hlist[i + 1]
            Hx = (prev_Hx + next_Hx) / 2  # Calculate average for line 12 only
        elif Hx == 0:  # Apply the 0-replacement rule to other lines
            Hx = handle_missing_values([Hx])[0]

        Tlist.append(Tx)
        Hlist.append(Hx)

        heat_index_val = cal_hi(Tx, Hx)
        stat = whatstatus(heat_index_val)
        print(f"{i+1}\t{Tx:.2f}\t\t{Hx:.2f}\t\t{heat_index_val:.2f}\t\t{stat}")

        if len(Tlist) % 30 == 0:
            input("Press <ENTER> to continue")
```

I want to it always take the (previous+next)/2 if it found a value 0

Answer (score 0):

First observation:

```py
        if Hx == 0:  # Check for 0 value specifically at index 11
            prev_Hx = Hlist[i - 1]
            next_Hx = Hlist[i + 1]
            Hx = (prev_Hx + next_Hx) / 2  # Calculate average for line 12 only
        elif Hx == 0:  # Apply the 0-replacement rule to other lines
            Hx = handle_missing_values([Hx])[0]
```

This part may be the problem because you're doing this in the same loop that constructs `Hlist` -- so the value at index `i+1` never exists. And your `elif` case is unreachable because it's testing the same condition as the `if` case.

My suggestion is to read in all the values into `Hlist`, pass `Hlist` through `handle_missing_values()` to clean it up, then loop over `Hlist` *again* and run the postprocessing code there (calculating the heat index, etc.):

```py
with open("blah") as Tf, blah blah:
    for Tl, Hl in zip(Tf, Hf):
        Tx = float(Tl.strip())
        Hx = float(Hl.strip())
        Tlist.append(Tx)
        Hlist.append(Hx)

    Hlist = handle_missing_values(Hlist)
    # same for Tlist if needed

    for Tx, Hx in zip(Tlist, Hlist):
        heat_index_val = cal_hi(Tx, Hx)
        stat = whatstatus(heat_index_val)
        print(f"{i+1}\t{Tx:.2f}\t\t{Hx:.2f}\t\t{heat_index_val:.2f}\t\t{stat}")
        # rest of your loop
```

Although I am a bit unclear on the requirements for the "boundary conditions" (i.e. when a zero is the first or last element) as implemented in `handle_missing_values()` -- in the case of the first element being zero the `max()` will clamp the index to 0 and you'll wind up taking the average of the first and second element which might not be what you want.

(P.S. Nice use of iterating over a file to read the lines. I often forget that I can do that and end up writing `for line in f.read().split('\n')` and use more memory than necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def interpolate_zeros(data):
    if not data:
        return

    yield(data[0])
    if len(data) == 1:
        return

    prev_it = iter(data)
    curr_it = iter(data); next(curr_it)
    next_it = iter(data); next(next_it); next(next_it)

    for prev_val, curr_val, next_val in zip(prev_it, curr_it, next_it):
        if curr_val == 0:
            yield (prev_val + next_val) / 2
        else:
            yield curr_val

    yield(data[-1])

data = [1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6]
print(list(interpolate_zeros(data)))
# -> [1, 2, 3.0, 4, 5.0, 6]
```

This might do what you expect when the first or last value in the list is zero, but you didn't specify how that should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate() and list comprehension. Assuming neither first not last element of your list is 0 below should work:

```
def handle_missing_values(dl):
    return [i if i != 0 else (dl[j-1]+dl[j+1])/2 for j,i in enumerate(dl)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your code and will need to use 2 loops

- First loop to create `Hlist` and `Tlist` from the files by iterating over lines
- Call `handle_missing_values` function twice to clean up `Hlist` and `Tlist`
- Second loop to do calculations - `heat_index_val` and `stat` by iterating over `Hlist` and `Tlist`

Also, since your `handle_missing_values` function already accounts for the edge cases, you wouldn't need the specific fixes.

My suggestion would be to use a global mean or nearest neighbor in case of one or both neighbors being invalid. Or else remove the 0 values all together before further processing. It depends on your use case though.

P.S. By the way, your `if` and `elif` conditions are both same and for all `Hx==0`, the code tries to access the elements at indices `i-1` and `i+1`, the latter of which is not yet generated  (Former also if i =0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` for it:

```py
import itertools


data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
prev_pool, current_pool, next_pool = itertools.tee(data, 3)
prev_pool = itertools.chain([-1], prev_pool)
next(next_pool)
next_pool = itertools.chain(next_pool, [-9])

for prev_element, current_element, next_element in zip(prev_pool, current_pool, next_pool):
    print(f"{prev_element=}, {current_element=}, {next_element=}")
```

Output:

```
prev_element=-1, current_element=1, next_element=2
prev_element=1, current_element=2, next_element=3
prev_element=2, current_element=3, next_element=4
prev_element=3, current_element=4, next_element=5
prev_element=4, current_element=5, next_element=6
prev_element=5, current_element=6, next_element=7
prev_element=6, current_element=7, next_element=-9
```

Notes

- We use `tee` to split the list into 3 iterables
- For `previous_pool`, we prepend the value `-1`. It can be anything that is convenient to our calculations
- For `next_pool`, we advance the pool and append `-9` to it. Again, this value can be anything that is covenient
- After that, we can zip the pools together and iterate through them